# Location client android

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I downloaded the samlpe geofence code.I have a doubt in the following code.

```
private void requestConnection() {
        getLocationClient().connect();

    }

    /**
     * Get the current location client, or create a new one if necessary.
     *
     * @return A LocationClient object
     */
    private GooglePlayServicesClient getLocationClient() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {

            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        }
        return mLocationClient;

    }
```

I dint understand this line

```
getLocationClient().connect();
```

getLocationClient is a method in the class but I dont know how .Connect came into the picture. Is it overriding? I know its something to do with OOP concepts. but missing it. Please help me on this

Comment: `getLocationClient()` return an object of type `GooglePlayServicesClient` and the class `GooglePlayServicesClient` define the method `connect()` and indeed this is really pure/basic/OOP/java syntax ;-)

Answer (score 0):

getLocationClient is a method in the class but I dont know how

Your class define that method "getLocationClient " which basically create a new instance of LocationClient and assigned it to the class variable mLocationClient ( if it was not previously assigned). See [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) for its use

method [connect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient.html#connect%28%29) is defined in the class LocationClient and since getLocationClient() returns an instance of LocationClient, hence the statement getLocationClient().connect() makes sense.

For info - LocationClient is use for  Google Location Services and the connect() method connects to Google Play services